# how to use IDL from application for unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com

the .exe of the application allows to dump IDL-definitions to a .IDL file.

with **midl** I can create a **.tlb** file.

But in C-compiler with the
**#import** statement
I got the **error** 
**cannot open source file** ... **.tlh**

How to fix it?

In VS Visual Basic project I'm able to use this application with the COM-Interface, but have other troubles with.

Thank you for advice
Erhy

Comment: #include requires C++.  Don't be misled by the IntelliSense parser, it will complain about a missing .tlh file at first.  Use Build > Build to ensure the .tlh file is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I done it like as Kim Gräsman advised in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854637/3127177

Here my way for the application TheServerApp :

all with installed **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017**

with **command line**

Search and execute **vcvars32.bat**

then execute

**oleview**

(if it makes problem the first time oleview.exe has to been executed as administrator)

in oleview window choose View TypeLibs

and open TheServerApp.exe

and then **File -> Save As**

So the **IDL definitions** are stored in TheServerApp.**idl**

**cd** where TheServerApp.IDL is located

and execute

**midl** TheServerApp.IDL

because I got the errors

TheServerApp.IDL(481) : error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type specification near "single"

Client\TheServerApp.IDL(481) : error MIDL2026 : cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation

I edited TheServerApp.IDL and replaced all words single with double

( see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/midl/midl-predefined-and-base-types) )

Now the execution of **midl** TheServerApp**.IDL**

results in the file TheServerApp**.tlb**

because #import TheServerApp.tlb in the Visual Studio project reports an error

write a small program imports.cpp in your project with the content:

```
// file to import with full path
**#import** " ... /**TheServerApp.tlb**"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
}
```

and in Command Line with executed vcvars32.bat as above

execute 
**cl ./imports.cpp**

which generates TheServerApp**.tlh** and TheServerApp**.tli**

in .cpp I included

```
#include "./TheServerApp.tlh"
#include "./TheServerApp.tli"
```

I generated also TheServerApp.dll, but don't know it will be needed further

tlbimp TheServerApp.tlb

which reports

TlbImp : Type library imported to TheServerApp.dll

so there is also the file TheServerApp.dll

for the next steps I have to study more

Erhy